# iTextSharp - corrupted PDF when combining memory streams

Tags: c#, itext

I'm generating multiple memory streams that need to be combined into a PDF using iTextSharp and then sent as attachment. However, the attached PDF in email upon opening shows an error that file is damaged.

Here is how I combine the memory streams:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    foreach (var seminar in seminars)
                    {
                        var reportBytes = await ssrsClient.GetReportAsync(_reportPath,
                            _detailedKostenkontrolleReportName, new {SeminarId = seminar.Id}).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        //Loop through each byte arrayforeach (var p in pdfByteContent) {​​​​

                        var reader = new PdfReader(reportBytes);

                        //Add the entire document instead of page-by-page
                        copy.AddDocument(reader);
                    }

                    var attachmentAllSeminarsDetailed = new Attachment(ms, DetailedAttachmentFileName,
                        "application/pdf");

                    attachments.Add(attachmentAllSeminarsDetailed);

                    //Create email body
                    sb = CreateEmailBody(
                        "Hallo,<br/><br/>in der Beilage sind die Berichte für die Hotelkostenkontrolle, die heute an die einzelne Hotels verschickt wurden.", "Dein SPOT - Team");

                    //Send e-mail with all PDF-s
                    MessageService.SendMessage(GetTestMailRecipients(), "Kostenkontrolle", sb.ToString(), attachments, new MailAddress(DefaultMailSender));
                }
            }
        }
```

The size of the PDF comes to 139 bytes but in code it is in correct size, ~180 kb. I have a feeling some of the documents or readers are not closed properly but I cannot figure out which one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to rewind the stream after the foreach loop? ( `ms.Position = 0;` )

Comment: @Fildor Yes, but I still get error about damage file when opening the PDF.

Comment: Not sure, if the document needs to be closed, first ...

Comment: Indeed. The document must be closed to finish the pdf. If you want to use the ms further, set stream closing to false